# Equivalent of BackgroundImageLayout in WPF Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Windows Forms enables us to set the image layout of background images like this:

```
(GetDesignSurface(tabControl1.SelectedTab) as System.Windows.Forms.UserControl).BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

Now, how do I do achieve the same for a canvas in WPF (System.Windows.window) ?

```
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BckImgDict[CurrentForm])); //ib is imagebrush
this.canvas1.Background = ib;
```

There are apparently no properties that allow me to achieve this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ib` is an `ImageBrush` it gives you 2 properties

[`AlignmentX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.alignmentx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of content in the TileBrush base tile.

[`AlignmentY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.alignmenty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the vertical alignment of content in the TileBrush base tile.

so in you code you should be able to do

```
ib.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center;
ib.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center;
```

you may also need to set `Stretch`, from default `Fill` value, to `None`

```
ib.Stretch = Stretch.None;
```